# Construct TM that will accepts the language L = {0i0j0k/ i < j < k}

Tags: state-machine, turing-machines

How to Construct a Turing Machine that will accepts the language      L = {0i0j0k/ i < j < k}.

Answer (score 0):

I take this to mean the language `0^i 0^j 0^k | i < j < k`. At least, I don't see any other obvious interpretations of it.

The shortest string in this language is obtained by taking `i = 0`, `j = 1` and `k = 2`'; this yields the string `000` in the language.

Note also that all strings of more than three zeroes are also in the language since we can take `i = 0`, `j = 1` and `k = n - 1` (for `n >= 3`).

Our language is thus equal to `0^n | n >= 3`. This language is regular. A minimal DFA for this language is as follows:

```
Q    s    Q'
q0   0    q1
q1   0    q2
q2   0    q3
q3   0    q3
```

Here, `q3` is the only accepting state and `q0` is the initial state. This assumes the input alphabet consists only of `0`; if it consists of more than that, you will need a dead state and extra productions.

Translating from a DFA to a TM is left as an exercise.